# Vue extend a class that has an import

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I've defined an import on a component. I then have another component that extends off of it. How would I go about defining and accessing the `Service` that the parent component has imported?

Service

```
export default {
    getSomeData() {
        return [1,2,3,4]
    }
}
```

Parent Component

```
import Service from '../service';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            testData: 'test'
        }
    }
}
```

Child Component

```
import Component from '../component';

export default {
    extends: Component,

    mounted() {
        console.log(Service.getSomeData()); // [1,2,3,4] Doesn't work, Service not defined.
        console.log(this.testData); // 'test' Works
    }
}
```

Generally I would just import `Service` in the child component and use that function. How do I define it in the parent so that I can access it in the child without having to import it again for other children?  I would prefer not to make it into a Vue component and extend it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign it to a data property:

```
import Service from '../service';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            testData: 'test',
            service: Service
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Component from '../component';

export default {
    extends: Component,

    mounted() {
        console.log(this.service.getSomeData()); // [1,2,3,4]
        console.log(this.testData); // 'test' Works
    }
}
```